# Warning: did not converge in 10 iterations in k-means clustering in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, warnings, cluster-computing, knn

I trying to find optimal number of cluster by using Gap statistic. I have already increased iter.max to 50:

###### Gap statistic

```
set.seed(123)
fviz_nbclust(data.s[, -c(1)], kmeans, nstart = 25,  method = "gap_stat", nboot = 1000)+
  labs(subtitle = "Gap statistic method",iter.max=50)
```

However, the coverage problem is not solved and I still got the following warning:

```
Warning: did not converge in 10 iterations
......Warning: did not converge in 10 iterations
.Warning: did not converge in 10 iterations
....Warning: did not converge in 10 iterations
.Warning: did not converge in 10 iterations
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem you are having is that you included the iter.max=50 within the labs instead of the fviz_nbclust function. Try this,

```
set.seed(123)
fviz_nbclust(data.s[, -c(1)], kmeans, nstart = 25,  method = "gap_stat", nboot = 1000, iter.max=50)+
  labs(subtitle = "Gap statistic method")
```